# Puppeteer, instagram, proxy

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, puppeteer

I'm currently trying to access Instagram using Puppeteer, and while everything works fine on my local machine, I'm receiving an error 429 when using the same script on my server. I find this strange because I'm using a proxy with the same IP address on both my local and remote servers.

I'm using Puppeteer-extra with stealth mode and the following arguments:

```
args = [
    '--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required',
    '--disable-background-networking',
    '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
    '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
    '--disable-breakpad',
    '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection',
    '--disable--component-update',
    '--disable-default-apps',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    '--disable-domain-reliability',
    '--disable-extensions',
    '--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess',
    '--disable-hang-monitor',
    '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection',
    '--disable-notifications',
    '--disable-offer-store-unmasked-wallet-cards',
    '--disable-popup-blocking',
    '--disable-print-preview',
    '--disable-prompt-on-repost',
    '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--disable-speech-api',
    '--disable-sync',
    '--hide-scrollbars',
    '--ignore-gpu-blacklist',
    '--metrics-recording-only',
    '--mute-audio',
    '--no-default-browser-check',
    '--no-first-run',
    '--no-pings',
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--no-zygote',
    '--password-store=basic',
    '--use-gl=swiftshader',
    '--use-mock-keychain',
    '--disable-web-security',
    '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins',
    '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
    '--disable-features=BlockInsecurePrivateNetworkRequests',
    `--proxy-server=${randomProxy.host}`
  ];
```

I'm wondering what could be causing the 429 error if not the IP address.

Comment: To ensure that the proxy configuration is correct, I utilized Puppeteer to make a request to https://api.myip.com/. The request was successful, indicating that the proxy is functioning properly. Therefore, the issue is not related to the proxy configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP Error 429` means `Too Many Requests`. [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)

Looks like you're always using the same proxy? In that case, you might consider implementing proxy-rotation with residential proxies. Free ones usually don't work or are blocked. You can buy cheap ones for example from asocks

Comment: Thank you, yes I know, but is still non-sense that with the really same proxy I'll get 429 online and 200 on locale